# Globally change terminal background in centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, terminal, colors

I can globally change text in terminal using .bashrc, but I can't figure out how to change the white background to black. Going to terminal preferences doesn't work either.

Comment: Which terminal emulator do you use (`xterm`, `gnome-terminal`,...)?

Comment: its the gnome-terminal

Comment: So in terminal click right mouse button -> profiles -> profile preferences -> colors -> background -> choose black.

Comment: I tried that it didn't work

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? The options are missing? Some error appears?...

Comment: I changed it, it shows that I'm using/editing profile "black" and I set the background to black, but it's still white

Answer (score 2):

Been struggling with this too. Finally found out you have to deselect "use colors from my system theme" checkbox for custom settings to take effect

Comment: Yep, that did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use black background go to Edit-Preferences and select "Use dark theme" checkbox

Comment: Since the question is not very specific, you should be precise about which terminal emulator your answer applies to.

Answer (score 0):

- For ls, modify the LS_COLORS, in your .bashrc or .profile

  export LS_COLORS="rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:"

https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console

- For vi, create the file .vimrc with contents

  set background=dark